# Merge row values into a single column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset `df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['TOM','TOM','DOM','DOM','DOM'],'ID':['a101','a101','b102','b102','b102'],'Col1':['Alpha','Alpha','Beta','Beta','Delta'],'Col2':['CLT','VERON','CLT','VERON','VERON'],'Col3':['FLA','SLG','SLG','DT-I','DT-I']})`

Where I want to merge column values against the `ID` column, such that my output table looks like this.

```
Name    ID  Type
TOM   a101  Alpha
TOM   a101  CLT
TOM   a101  FLA
TOM   a101  VERON
TOM   a101  SLG
DOM   b102  Beta
DOM   b102  VERON
DOM   b102  DT-I
DOM   b102  Delta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = (df.set_index(['Name', 'ID']).stack()
         .droplevel(-1).reset_index(name='Type')
         .drop_duplicates()
      )
```

Output:

```
   Name    ID   Type
0   TOM  a101  Alpha
1   TOM  a101    CLT
2   TOM  a101    FLA
4   TOM  a101  VERON
5   TOM  a101    SLG
6   DOM  b102   Beta
7   DOM  b102    CLT
8   DOM  b102    SLG
10  DOM  b102  VERON
11  DOM  b102   DT-I
12  DOM  b102  Delta
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `melt`

```
out = df.melt(['Name','ID'], value_name = 'Type').drop(['ID'] ,axis = 1).drop_duplicates()
   Name variable   Type
0   TOM     Col1  Alpha
2   DOM     Col1   Beta
4   DOM     Col1  Delta
5   TOM     Col2    CLT
6   TOM     Col2  VERON
7   DOM     Col2    CLT
8   DOM     Col2  VERON
10  TOM     Col3    FLA
11  TOM     Col3    SLG
12  DOM     Col3    SLG
13  DOM     Col3   DT-I
```